# Integrability condition in Jensen's inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, jensen-inequality

I'm reading about Jensen's inequality from a lecture [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc1_final.pdf):

> If $X$ is a random variable and $\psi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex and such that $\mathbb{E}(|\psi(X)|)<\infty$, then
> $$
> \psi(\mathbb{E}(X)) \leq \mathbb{E}(\psi(X)) .
> $$
> In particular, $|\mathbb{E}(X)| \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|)$.

It seems there is no guarantee that "$\psi(X)$ is integrable implies $X$ is integrable". As such, we don't know whether $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and thus $\psi(\mathbb{E}(X))$ are well-defined or not. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: You are correct. It is enough to assume that $E(|X|) < \infty$. Then $E(\psi(X)^{-}) < \infty$ and Jensen's inequality holds.

Comment: @Mason You meant $E(|X|) < \infty \implies E(|\psi(X)|) < \infty$. Could you elaborate on how to prove it?

Comment: You don't get $E[\psi(X)]<\infty$. The inequality is allowed to be satisfied on the extended real numbers, as for example the left being a real number and the right being $+\infty$.

Comment: See a [proof here](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf#page=77). In particular the note under Theorem 3.3 is talking precisely about that case.

Comment: @user85667 Theorem 3.3 in that book imposes a strong condition that $f$ takes values in $(a, b)$ which is relatively compact. This combining with the fact that $\varphi$ is continuous implies $\varphi \circ f$ is $\mu$-integrable.

Comment: Read carefully. $a,b$ are allowed to be $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. All is being excluded is $X$ taking the value $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much!